# How to stop timer when enter to background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I have one timer that will countdown the time to 0. timer stop fine when it reach to 0 and when clicking submit button but timer doesn't stop when go out the application and come back.
I tried to create the timer in `viewWillAppear` and `invalidate` it in `viewWillDisappear` but timer still running after coming back from background. How to stop timer when enter to background? Any sample?

Thanks

Comment: i think u must try in app delegate .in - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter`. Add observer for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and stop your timer in it. You won't have to create your timer in AppDelegate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

method of appDelegate class to stop your time . But for that you have to declare the timer inside the appDelegate class. Also you have to persist the counter when you will go to background .

Then you can use the  `viewWillAppear:`
method to restart the timer.